# Losing data bit when reading from GPIO by libgpiod on Linux

Tags: c, embedded-linux, gpio, iio, libgpiod

I am using Debian (8.3.0-6)  on an embedded custom board and working on the dht11 sensor.
**Briefly,**
I need to read 40 bits from a GPIO pin and each bit can take a max 70 microseconds. When bit-level is high for max 28us or 70us, it means is logic 0 or 1, respectively. (So I have a timeout controller for each bit and if a bit takes more than 80us, I need to stop the process.).
[image]
[image]
In my situation, sometimes I can read all 40 bits correctly but sometimes I can't do it and the function of libgpiod `gpiod_line_get_value(line);` is missing the bit (my code is below). I am trying to figure out that why I cant read and lose a bit, what is the reason for that. But I haven't found a sensible answer yet. So I was wondering **What am I missing out?, What is the proper way to GPIO programming?**

Here is what I wanted to show you, How do I understand what I am missing a bit? Whenever I catch a bit, I am setting and resetting another GPIO pin at the rising and falling edge of a bit (So I can see which bit missing). **Moreover, as far as I see  I am always missing** the two edges on one bit or one edge on two bits consecutively (rising and falling or falling and rising). In the first picture, you can see which bit I missed, the second is when I read all bits correctly.

[image]

[image]

Here it is my code:

```c
//********************************************************* Start reading data bit by low level (50us) ***************************
    for (int i = 0; i < DHT_DATA_BYTE_COUNT ; i++) //DHT_DATA_BYTE_COUNT = 5
    {
        for (int J = 7; J > -1; J--)
        {
             GPIO_SetOutPutPin(testPin); //gpiod_line_set_value(testPin, 1);
             int ret;
             start = micros();
             do
             {
                 ret = GPIO_IsInputPinSet(dht11pin);//gpiod_line_get_value(dht11pin);
                 delta = micros() - start;
                 if(ret == -1)
                 {
                     err_step.step = 9;
                    err_step.ret_val = -1;
                    return -1;
                 }
                if(delta > DHT_START_BIT_TIMEOUT_US) //80us
                {
                    err_step.step = 10;
                    err_step.ret_val = -2;
                    err_step.timestamp[is] = delta;
                    err_step.indx[is].i = i;
                    err_step.indx[is++].j = J;
                    GPIO_ResetOutPutPin(testPin);
                    return -2;
                }
             }while(ret == 0);


                GPIO_ResetOutPutPin(testPin);
                err_step.ret_val = 10;


                GPIO_SetOutPutPin(testPin);

            start = micros();
            do
             {
                 ret = GPIO_IsInputPinSet(dht11pin);
                 delta = micros() - start;
                 if(ret == -1)
                 {
                     err_step.step = 11;
                    err_step.ret_val = -1;
                    return -1;
                 }
                 if(delta > DHT_BEGIN_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_US) //80us
                {
                    err_step.step = 12;
                    err_step.ret_val = -2;
                    err_step.timestamp[is] = delta;
                    err_step.indx[is].i = i;
                    err_step.indx[is++].j = J;
                    return -2;
                }
             }while(ret == 1);

                    err_step.timestamp[is] = delta;
                    err_step.indx[is].i = i;
                    err_step.indx[is++].j = J;
                GPIO_ResetOutPutPin(testPin);
                err_step.ret_val = 10;

            (delta > DHT_BIT_SET_DATA_DETECT_TIME_US) ? bitWrite(dht11_byte[i],J,1) : bitWrite(dht11_byte[i],J,0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That subtle signal timing is not going to be reliable in user mode code. Linux kernel version 3.14 onwards has a dht11 driver selected by `CONFIG_DHT11` and is part of the Linux Industrial I/O subsystem. It needs a GPIO line that supports interrupts on rising and falling edges. It needs to be configured in the device tree. See the device tree bindings at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/iio/humidity/dht11.txt or https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/iio/humidity/dht11.yaml

Comment: What do you mean by signal timing?Could you elaborate it please. Do you mean I get the time by micros and I calculate the differences? if it exceeds the threshold, I stop the reading in the code above. if you mean is that. my problem is not that. briefly, why gpiod reading funct.(gpiod_line_get_value) cannot catch the bit. Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I'll check these links to understand. I am new at linux gpio programming on Linux. So I just wanted to figure out from simple way to proper / in a perfect way

Comment: By the way, I calculate the percentage of corruption of data, it is % 83. I collected 12288 data with a sec interval, 10267 of them are corrupt data. Absolutely, it is unreliable.

Comment: Use in-kernel driver as @IanAbbott suggested. And use `libiio`. It has a lot of nice features and good documentation.

Comment: if there is someone interested in the differences between userspace gpio programming and kernel gpio programming. I also observed the percentage of corruption in kernel gpio programming on dht11 sensor. it was % 62. I collected 4714 temp and humidity data and 2933 of them was corrupted. Only 1788 of them was acceptable correct data.